# How to debug a javascript injected page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking at popular LinkedIn post feature, the three dots seems to trigger html injection inside specific tags. My first question would be, why they did this choice, however what really interest me, is how can I debug and understand the mechanics involved, since when I inspect the page with firefox I cannot find the starting point nor the triggers to control this pop-up trigger?

[image]

Comment: LinkedIn uses [Ember.js](https://emberjs.com/). Because of this, portions of the js/html structure will be unusual since they're generated by algorithm. In this case, the handler that deals with opening and closing the three-dot buttons is likely attached to the `<body>` element. The dynamic insertion is likely due to how Ember.js's component system works.

Comment: What approach should I use to debug it? Is it possible to inject additional options in the generated menu?